# SSH Tunnel from Windows through Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, tunnel

I'd like to establish an SSH tunnel via a Linux jump host in the following way:

Host A is Windows-based and has a private key to authenticate with the jump host (Host B)
Host B is Linux-based and has a different user with a private key to authenticate with hosts in the DMZ
Host C is Windows-based and is only reachable from host B via SSH (or physically)
I have tried `ssh -v -N user2@HostC -J user1@HostB -L [port]:HostC:[remote_port]` and it's working, but only with a password, it keeps asking for it despite having keys on all necessary hosts.

Could anyone help on this topic?

P.S. It works if I use the same key pair on all three hosts, but I would like to use different users with different key pairs because of security reasons.

Comment: What does OpenSSH indicate is the problem (per the logs)

Comment: You wrote that very misleadingly. You should say HostC not C, otherwise you make it look like some new thing in ssh or an error or at best, could be much clearer. I have made that adjustment to your syntax

Comment: You're right, sorry and thanks for the correction! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Preliminary notes

- I don't use Windows but hopefully it won't matter much.
- Often when I say "A", "B", "C", I really mean "the user on A", "user1 on B", "user2 on C" respectively. E.g. "the B's key" means "user1's key available on B". This is for brevity.

---

#### Analysis

This is [how `-J` works](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J):

> `-J destination`
> Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the jump host described by `destination` and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.

This means `ssh -J user1@B user2@C` is *not* equivalent to connecting from A to B and then from B to C. It's equivalent to connecting from A to B and then from A to C (using packets forwarded through B). No SSH client is invoked on B, so the key that allows you to connect from B to C is never used.

---

#### Solution

The most elegant way to solve the general problem is to make C accept the (or an) A's key. You said:

> It works if I use the same key pair on all three hosts, but I would like to use different users with different key pairs because of security reasons.

You can use different pairs. I understand there's currently a key pair that allows you to connect from A to B and a separate pair that allows B to C. The latter is irrelevant. On C authorize any key A uses to authenticate. It may be the old key (the one already authorized on B); but it may be a new key created exclusively for this connection.

Then, when you do `ssh -J user1@B user2@C` on A, you need to use the key that allows A to connect to B *and* the key that allows A to connect to C. If they are different keys, you need to use them both. Use [`-i`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#i) once or even twice if needed.

---

#### Alternative solution

You can use the already registered keys if you actually connect from B to C after connecting from A to B. If you wanted to log in from A to C, then it would be like:

```
# from A
ssh -t user1@B 'ssh user2@C'
```

<sup>(at least in Linux; I'm not sure how quoting works in Windows).</sup>

This command runs `ssh` on B to connect to C, so it will use the B's key.

---

#### About port forwarding

Your original command used `-N` and `-L`, so I understand the only goal is to forward a port. You forwarded the port using the A-to-C connection and the destination was also C; so the last leg for forwarded packets was from the SSH server on C to C. *Maybe* the `[remote_port]` is reachable from B. If so, then you don't need any of the above solutions; all you need is:

```
ssh -NL [port]:C:[remote_port] user1@B
```

This will make the last leg for forwarded packets be from the SSH server on B to C.

If the last leg must be from C to C, then the course of action depends on which solution you choose.

- The solution with an A's key authorized on C will allow you to use your original command without passwords.
- The solution with running `ssh` on B will require you to forward the port from A to B and separately from B to C. Something like:

  ```
  ssh -L [port]:localhost:[relay_port] user1@B 'ssh -NL [relay_port]:C:[remote_port] user2@C'
  ```

Comment: This worked, and also, thanks for the detailed explanations, I understand it a lot more clearly now! :)