# Multistep ssh - is it possible?

Tags: ssh

Let's say there are 3 computers A B and C. B and C are remote computers but in the same local network.

I SSH into computer B from computer A. Is it now possible to ssh into C from B?

Comment: it's called a SSH multi-hop and the same can be accomplished via a bastion server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is entirely possible.  Not only that but there are ways to automate this process within SSH (more then 1 in fact).

Many "secure" systems use this approach where server C only trust server B, and everyone needs to SSH through it.  The name for this kind of host is called a bastion.

- As mentioned, you can SSH to B, then from B you can SSH to C.

You can also set up B to authenticate and forward a connection to C without even getting a shell on B - either by using SSH forwarding or by having SSHon B  recognise the log in and immediately log in to C.

Comment: Although they accomplish the same end goal, a SSH multi-hop and Bastion [server] setup are two completely different things.

Comment: @jw0914 - I acknowledge that multihop ssh and bastions are not synoyms, but disagree they are completely different - especially as I said SSH through, not to it -  but please explain how you see it. (Support for my interpretation - https://www.learningjournal.guru/article/public-cloud-infrastructure/what-is-bastion-host-server/   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host https://cloudacademy.com/blog/aws-bastion-host-nat-instances-vpc-peering-security/ )

Comment: Generally when "bastion" is used, it's used in the context of a dedicated Bastion Server for Bastion Hosts. For example, I run Sophos UTM on a custom-built router & to SSH into any downstream devices, I must do a SSH multi-hop, however that doesn't make my router a Bastion Server, as a Bastion Server is a specific thing that must be configured, else we'd call every SSH server a Bastion Server. A sentence in the Cloud Academy AWS blog provides more context: _"When designing the bastion host [server] ... you shouldn’t use it for any other purpose, as this could open unnecessary security holes"_.

Comment: @jw0914 In that case we agree on what a Bastion is.

Comment: Your comment in regards to the context of what you're disputing makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is not only possible but also quite common, and therefore a supported use case; the correct search terms for this are *bastion host*, *jump host*, or *ssh proxy*.

- The best way is to use the [`ProxyJump`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyJump) option of `ssh`, specified with the [`-J` flag](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J), which will establish a connection to hostC through hostB:

  ```sh
  # on host A
  ssh -J userB@hostB userC@hostC
  ```
- A more flexible option is the [`ProxyCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand) option, which can use *any* command to connect to the target host using stdin/stdout of the command:

  ```sh
  ssh -o ProxyCommand "ssh userB@hostB -W %h:%p" userC@hostC
  ```

  This will first start a second `ssh` client connecting to hostB and [`-W`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#W) will connect its stdin/stdout to hostC [`%h`] on the ssh port [`%p`].
- For more convenience, you can specify all these options in your `.ssh/config`, allowing you to connect with just `ssh hostC`:

  ```sh
  Host hostC
    User userC
    ProxyJump userB@HostB
    # alternatively using ProxyCommand:
    #ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p userB@hostB
  ```

If for some reason both `ProxyJump` and `ProxyCommand`/`ssh -W %h:%p` are not available to you, you could setup tunneled port forwarding yourself:

```sh
# start a ssh process in the background to forward
# from localhost (host A) port 2222 to port 22 on hostC from hostB
ssh -f -N -L localhost:2222:hostC:22 userB@hostB

# connect to localhost:2222 which is tunneled to hostC:22
ssh -p 2222 userC@localhost
```

Comment: A Bastion server is not the same thing as a SSH proxy/SSH multi-hop, even though they accomplish the exact same thing: generally, when "Bastion" is used, it's used in the context of a dedicated Bastion server. For example, I run Sophos UTM on a custom-built router and to SSH into any downstream devices, I must do a SSH multi-hop; however, that doesn't make my router a Bastion server, as a Bastion server is a specific thing that must be configured, else we'd call every SSH server a Bastion server. Bastion servers are usually secured in their own environment, with no other purpose, for security.

Comment: Ultimately the OP wants "to ssh into C from B". Your `ssh -J userB@hostB userC@hostC` does *not* ssh from B. See the analysis in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1565588/432690). The difference may not matter for the OP; but in general, in some circumstances it may matter.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski correct: with this will ultimately establish a direct ssh connection between host A and host C but tunneled through another ssh connection to host B. This will not involve the ssh _client_ on host B; which is what I understood @vahagn-tumanyan wanting to achieve. Otherwise if the connection should be made from host B it's indeed something completely different but also even simpler: just `ssh userB@hostB ssh userC@hostC`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski While I interpreted the OP's question the same way as acran, your interpretation is equally valid as it depends upon which way you read it.

Comment: @acran Just an FYI, the line you thought was dropped in the edit is still there, it was just combined into the originating sentence for grammatical correctness, as breaking a sentence before and after a code box leaves it discombobulated: _"For more convenience, you can specify all these options in your `.ssh/config`, allowing you to connect with just `ssh hostC`"_

Answer (score 0):

Well, if system B can reach system C via tcp port 22 and there is an SSH daemon running on C where you have a valid user for - yes!

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer...

Comment: It is an answer - see the last word.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what constitutes an answer... please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers). Leaving this answer as is will result in an accumulation of down votes as more come across.

Comment: @jw0914 I think these ARE valid answers and certainly fit within the guidelines you linked to. The question is simple enough that it demands no more then a yes or no in response. I'm genuinely surprised the answers were down voted to -2. ( I upvoted them back to -1)

Comment: @davidgo A yes/no statement isn't really an answer in the context of StackExchange _(I've never come across upvoted answers with a simple yes or no statement as the entire answer; perhaps you have?)_, as it lacks either an explanation or how to perform a multi-hop, either of which was my interpretation of the intent of the OP's question _(then again, it could be I simply have a high bar for answers)_. As currently written, this answer would be better served as a comment, however if the author chooses to take the time to flesh out this answer, I'll remove my downvote and would likely upvote it.

Comment: @davidgo Is there really an explanation needed how to perform a multi-hop? If one does ssh from A to B, one essentially works on machine B now; so just run ssh to C from there. What is there to explain?