# Downloading a Directory via SSH through JumpHost server to the destination server

Tags: linux, windows, download, remote, ssh-tunnel

Updated statement.
I ssh through a jumphost and into a destination server:
ssh -i jumphost.pem user@jumphostip
then I ssh into the destination from the jumphost:
ssh -i server_dsa user@serverdestination

I have not made an .ssh/config file for this.

I want to be able to download a directory from the destination server to my local (windows) pc.  With the knowledge of logging into the jump host and then into the destination server my best guess was something like:

scp -i jumphost.pem user@jumphostip -i server_dsa -r user@serverdestination:/file/path/for/directory .

The syntax is off, but I'm trying to copy the directory recursively through the jumphost from the destination server to my current folder on my pc.

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you ssh into the destination server? Do you use `ProxyJump` in the ssh config? or in the command line? or `-J` in the command line? Or do you manually ssh to the jumphost and then manually to the destination from there? Please respond by [edit]ing the question and adding information to the question body.

Comment: After adding the ssh keys, I've been manually logging in using the command line:
ssh -i jumphost.pem user@jumhostip
ssh -i server_dsa user@destination

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure about the syntax of the command you posted related to the identity file, so first, try to modify your .ssh/config to specify which identity file to use with which host:

```
Host jumphostip    
 IdentityFile jumphost.pem 
Host serverdestination   
 IdentityFile server_dsa
```

Then use the -J option (from man page):

> -J destination
> Connect to the target host by first making an scp connection to the jump host described by destination and then
> establishing a TCP for‐
> warding to the ultimate destination from there.  Multiple jump hops may be specified separated by comma characters.  This is a
> shortcut to
> specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.  This option is directly passed to ssh(1).

```
scp -r -J user@jumphostip user@serverdestination:/file/path/for/directory .
```

Comment: I'm upvoting the answer because `-J` (or `ProxyJump` in the config) is a reasonable approach. It may or may not fit the OP's setup though. Considering how `-J` works (see the analysis [here](https://superuser.com/a/1565588/432690)), one cannot use an identity file existing on the jumphost. The answer assumes `server_dsa` is available on the client. But *maybe* the asker expects a file from the jumphost to be used (because maybe they interactively `ssh` to the jumphost and then `ssh -i server_dsa` further). In such case your answer won't work out of the box.

Comment: you are right, the question needs clarification

Comment: Thanks for taking a crack at it.  I restructured my question hoping to improve the clarity.  Is this something that requires an ssh_config file?

No identity files used are on the jumphost, they exist locally.

Comment: @Sierra Your statements "then I ssh into the destination from the jumphost: `ssh -i server_dsa user@serverdestination`" and "no identity files used are on the jumphost" contradict each other.

Comment: @AlexandreLussier  Perhaps.  The jumphost.pem and server_dsa keys are in a local directory on my pc.  I ssh-add them prior to logging in to either jumphost or the destination server.  So I see what you're saying, but my understanding is that no identity file is on the jumphost - that could be my misperception though.

Comment: @Sierra did you tried setting the identity file with the -J option?
scp -r -J user@jumphostip -i server_dsa user@serverdestination:/file/path/for/directory .