# SSH tunnel: the middle host has the key to the final host

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I'd like to implement a (temporary, won't be a stable configuration) SSH tunnel, so I can SSH to box C from box A going through B.

```
A--->B--->C
```

I learnt that it can be done by running 2 commands on A:

```
ssh userB@B -L PORT:A:22
ssh userC@localhost -p PORT
```

The problem is that this works as long as authentication can be performed from box A, for example box C asks for userC's password, the password is prompted on box A and typed. In my case, however, the way to access box C is a key that's stored on box B (so, from box B, one just types `ssh userC@C` and is not prompted for a password). Box A just sees the message `Permission denied (publickey)`.

Is there a way to allow access in this case?

Comment: See the "alternative solution" in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1565588/432690).

Comment: Just an FYI, the name for what you're doing is an SSH multi-hop _(it is a stable way to access hosts, often used to SSH into LAN devices through a router's WAN SSH server)_

Comment: Now I notice your "2 commands on A" allow you to reach `userC@A`. *If there is no typo* (did you mean `-L PORT:C:22`?) and A gets `Permission denied (publickey)` then this only means A's key is not enough to log in as `userC` at A. C is not involved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kamil Maciorowski, the answer they referred to helped. Both `ssh -J userB@B userC@C` and `ssh userB@B 'ssh userC@C'` work. I found the former more suited to my specific need

Comment: OK, I guess. Although I'm surprised `ssh -J` works for you, if A (allegedly) is not authorized to access C. See my new comment under the question.